# Change default monospace font for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

Is there  a way to change the default monospace font for Windows 7, like it is in Ubuntu? It's true that I can configure for every application I use, but I don't want to do that.

I want that every application that defaults to using Ms Console or Lucida Console automatically uses another monospace font that I have installed.

Comment: Windows has no such notion of "default" fonts.  Many developers pick something like Lucida Console or Courier New (or Consolas for Vista+ systems) simply because they're built into Windows.  The next best thing you can do is remove the font that you don't want to see and use the `FontSubstitutes` registry key to make sure that any application requesting that font gets the one you want instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has no such notion of "default" fonts. Many developers pick something like Lucida Console or Courier New (or Consolas for Vista+ systems) simply because they're built into Windows. The next best thing you can do is remove the font that you don't want to see and use the `FontSubstitutes` registry key to make sure that any application requesting that font gets the one you want instead.

The only part I'm not sure about is if it's going to be easy to remove built-in fonts without tripping Windows File Protection.

Comment: Really? No default font setting? That sucks. Linux desktops have it. I am sick and tired of numerous number of programming-related applications' displaying the ugly Courier New. I have been changing it to Consolas, but repeating it is tedious. Why the heck do developers pick that eyesore Courier New when Consolas also come with Windows?

Comment: Isn't `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Codepage\1252\FixedWidthFont` the setting? I found this by searching with "Courier New", and I am not sure what exactly it is but it does not seem to be tied to a specific application, so maybe a system-wide setting?

Answer (score 3):

[TweakFix's answer](https://superuser.com/a/412018/8972) is the closest thing to an answer for system-wide settings you will get as different applications all have their own settings for this.  For some apps you may be able to change it in their .ini files, or their registry entries.

For CMD, you can add additional monospace fonts to the list by editing and then running this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Installs additonal font in the Windows Command Prompt as per Microsoft KB247815

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont]
"000000"="font name"
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess i will have to change it for every application individually.

Comment: Then where does Eclipse find a font when you click on "Use System Font" in Preferences -> General / Appearence / Colors and Fonts ?